# Put favorite icon outsite the web site root folder

Tags: favicon

I need to put favicon.ico outside the root of the web site.
Can i place it in another path or it may penalize some old browser?

Comment: @DanielMorgan: Not in this case.  He's asking whether it will break obscure browsers.

Answer (score 17):

If you put `favicon.ico` in another directory and declare it in the HTML (eg. `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/icon/favicon.ico">`), **the favicon will work**, including on IE5, the first browser to support favicons. However, you will encounter the following (minor) drawbacks:

- IE (and maybe some others) will look for `/favicon.ico` no matter what. Expect some 404 errors in your HTTP server logs.
- Some browsers, like Chrome, will use `favicon.ico` even if you also declare high resolution PNG favicon pictures. Of course, if you only use `favicon.ico` as the favicon picture, this is not a concern.

In general, this is a good practice to put all favicon-related file in the root directory of the web site. See http://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#why_icons_in_root for more information (full disclosure: I am the author of this page).

Comment: Works great in Waterfox (variation of Firefox) -- no server request to /favicon.ico and no error/warning in the console.

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers [will always check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon.ico#Limitations_and_criticism) for favicon.ico in the root folder.  Won't break anything if absent, though.